# PyCharm: Exporting Local History

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm on OSX, and I just found out about the local history feature. However, the local history for a file is only maintained for at most 23 days(Going beyond that causes local history to stop working), 5 by default.

I found two files named `changes.storageData` and `changes.storageRecordIndex` in `~/Library/Caches/PyCharm40/LocalHistory`, but these seem to be binary files.

Is it possible to export the local history for a project in PyCharm? Perhaps in git repository format?

Comment: Where do you see a history limit of 5 to 23 days?  Perhaps that's not longer configurable in PyCharm 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like PyCharm doesn't have any way of exporting local history, and JetBrains doesn't plan to add this functionality in the foreseeable future.

[Source](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117052)